# How to copy my faulty Cisco 2600 configuration to a working identical one using ethernet

Tags: cisco, configuration, backup-restoration

I'd have to make a backup copy of my Cisco 2600 router and restore it on another Cisco 2600.
Is it possible using ethernet cable and telnet or any other tool?
How?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... Very nearly a dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/224969/restoring-a-cisco-router-config-using-a-config-file

Comment: The answer I got is much more accurate but thanks you for the heads up: I can get a more complete scene reading both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to put up a TFTP server, accessible to the currently running router, and do  `copy running-config tftp:` and copy the configuration up to the TFTP server. If you've got a Windows machine handy, for example, you can get a [free TFTP server](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/) running pretty easily. Once you've got the configuration copied off, shut off the old router and disconnect it.

On the new router, connect it up and make a bare-bones configuration that sets an IP address and subnet mask on an interface connected to the network with the TFTP server. Verify you can PING the TFTP server from the router if that makes you comfortable. Then run a `copy tftp://x.x.x.x/filename startup-config` on the router (substituting in the IP address of the TFTP server and the filename you saved the old configuration into) to bring the configuration down into the new router. Reload the new router and your newly-copied configuration will be used.

Copying the configuration around with simple text capture tools (like PuTTY logging) will "miss" some configuration values (ipsec keys aren't reported in `show running-config`, for example).

Comment: To understand my other 2600 cisco config and accordingly edit the tftp server network values how can I check the 2600 network config?

A show config will give me the 2600 ip? Thanks :)